# Expo Router v3 does not recognize "_layout.tsx" in custom entry file

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

As far as I can tell, React Native Expo (SDK 50) with Expo Router v3 is not able to recognize a layout file when changing the entry file from "expo-router/entry".

I attempted the following:

project structure:
app/
nav/
page/
_layout.tsx
index.tsx <- custom entry point

package.json:

```
...
"main": "app/nav/page",
...
```

_layout.tsx:

```
import { Slot } from 'expo-router';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Layout</Text>
                <Slot />
        </View>
    );
}
```

index.tsx:

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function Page() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Page</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

registerRootComponent(Page);
```

This resulted in just the index.tsx page being rendered just fine, but without the layout wrapper.